# DPM 2010 End User Recovery Failing

Tags: dfs, scdpm

I have DPM2010 installed and I am using End User Recovery. I did not initially set it up. It is working for a few folders and on the DPM server in Share and Storage Manager I can see the shares in there that have it working. The problem is the ones in there are marked with a red X and if I try to go to the properties on them it tells me "Cannot verify that the folders exist. Illegal characters in path". The local path shows \?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft DPM\DPM\Volumes\Replica\File System\vol_XXXXXX\Full\Share Name. We use DFS and the shares are setup in DFS. These are the folders that I want to use EUR on so we can restore previous versions.

I read somewhere that there is an issue with DFS shares and EUR and they don't show up but if you type the full path name they do. There is a Microsoft article on this and a hotfix and that is **NOT** my issue. I can't see the previous versions from either place.

Things I have tried

- I have made sure EUR is enabled in DPM console for all shares
- I have tried to add a share to Share and Storage Manager on DPM share
- I have disabled local shadow copies
- Schema extension has been run

To finalize I know that when the DPM Share and Storage Manager show the share path(even with a red X) this means that EUR is working on that folder. But i can't figure out how it has put some in there and not the others?

Answer (score 1):

OK 27 views and no answers... I had to contact Microsoft in the end as I could not resolve this. Turns out the folders on the DFS server needed to have the "**System**" account in security permissions. Apparently this is needed for End User Recovery to work.

So I hope this helps somebody else out there as I was stumped by this issue!